# Updating State With componentDidUpdate() and React-APlayer Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state with data received from a fetch request in the parent component. I am using the ‘react-aplayer’ library (https://github.com/MoePlayer/react-aplayer) as an audio player.

I am able to hard-code songs into the playlist as shown in ‘this.state.audio’ below.  However, when trying to change this data to data received through props via the componentDidUpdate() method, I am not able to setState to the new data. When I console.log ‘this.state.audio’ to see the data, I get two messages: the first one with the hard-coded playlist info, and the next with my data received from the fetch request.

How do I update the state with the new data so that it replaces the hard-coded data?

Here is my component:

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactAplayer from '../react-aplayer';
import './AudioPlayer.css';

export default class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      theme: '#F57F17', //#F57F17,
      lrcType: 3,
      audio: [
        {
          name: "Song Title",
          artist: 'Artist Name',
          url: 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/os8v0ymru1433nn/2%20mix.wav',
          cover: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
          lrc: '',
          theme: '#46718b'
        },
        {
          name: "Next Song Title",
          artist: 'Next Artist Name',
          url: 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/os8v0ymru1433nn/2%20mix.wav',
          cover: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
          lrc: '',
          theme: '#46718b'
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (this.props.playlist !== prevProps.playlist) {

      const songs = this.props.playlist;
      const audio = Object.keys(songs).map(key => {
        return {
          name: songs[key].name,
          artist: songs[key].artist,
          url: songs[key].url,
          cover: songs[key].cover,
          lrc: songs[key].lrc,
          theme: songs[key].theme
        }
      });
      this.setState({ audio })
      this.setState({sample: 'hello'})
    }
  }

  // event binding example
  onPlay = () => {
    console.log('on play');
  };

  onPause = () => {
    console.log('on pause');
  };

  // example of access aplayer instance
  onInit = ap => {
    this.ap = ap;
  };


  render() {
  console.log('audio state', this.state.audio)

  const props = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
      <div className="landing">
      <div className="aplayer-wrap">
        {/* example with detailed props */}
        <ReactAplayer
          {...this.state}
          onInit={this.onInit}
          onPlay={this.onPlay}
          onPause={this.onPause}
        />
        </div>
        </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the react-aplayer component from that library that is called:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import APlayer from 'aplayer';
import 'aplayer/dist/APlayer.min.css';
import events from './events';

const capitalize = function(str) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
};

const eventsPropTypes = events.reduce((acc, event) => {
  acc[`on${capitalize(event)}`] = PropTypes.func;
  return acc;
}, {});

const audioItemShape = PropTypes.shape({
  name: PropTypes.string,
  artist: PropTypes.string,
  url: PropTypes.string,
  cover: PropTypes.string,
  lrc: PropTypes.string,
  theme: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string
});

class ReactAplayer extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onInit: PropTypes.func,
    // belows are the same props with aplayer
    fixed: PropTypes.bool,
    mini: PropTypes.bool,
    autoplay: PropTypes.bool,
    theme: PropTypes.string,
    loop: PropTypes.oneOf(['all', 'one', 'none']),
    order: PropTypes.oneOf(['list', 'random']),
    preload: PropTypes.oneOf(['auto', 'metadata', 'none']),
    volume: PropTypes.number,
    audio: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      audioItemShape,
      PropTypes.arrayOf(audioItemShape)
    ]),
    customAudioType: PropTypes.object,
    mutex: PropTypes.bool,
    lrcType: PropTypes.number,
    listFolded: PropTypes.bool,
    listMaxHeight: PropTypes.string,
    storageName: PropTypes.string,
    // belows are bind event listener
    ...eventsPropTypes
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    onInit() {},
    fixed: false,
    mini: false,
    autoplay: false,
    theme: '#b7daff',
    loop: 'all',
    order: 'list',
    preload: 'auto',
    volume: 0.7,
    mutex: true,
    lrcType: 0,
    listFolded: false,
    storageName: 'react-aplayer-setting'
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { onInit, ...restProps } = this.props;

    const control = new APlayer({
      ...restProps,
      container: this.container
    });

    events.forEach(event => {
      const funcName = 'on' + capitalize(event);
      const callback = this.props[funcName];
      if (callback) {
        control.on(event, callback);
      }
    });

    this.control = control;
    onInit(control);
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => (this.container = el)} />;
  }
}

export default ReactAplayer;
```

Comment: Are you sure `componentDidUpdate` is being called, can you log before your if statement and before you call setState and see if either/both are logged

Comment: Yes, I console.logged 'this.props.playlist' before the if statement within componentDidMount() and before the setState() within that method and received the response from my fetched data.

Comment: Are you by chance using react router to render your component, depending on how it's being rendered you can cause mounting and un-mounting, try adding thee fucntion componentDidMount and log, if it logs more than once then you know your component is being unmounted which would cause the state to reinitialize

Comment: I get an empty array when I console.log 'this.props.playlist' in componentDidMount(). I am using react router in the main App.js file of the project.

Comment: Did it log more than once is the main concern, if so we know it's being unmounted and mounted back

Comment: No, it only logged once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting back and forth it seems that this may be an issue with how React itself views your props and the order in which updates come in.

If you insist on updating your state from props then I recommend using the safer `getDerivedStateFromProps` method which was introduced for issues like the one you're facing.

[Updating state from props](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state) (when/how to use and why this method exists)

The second is to solely use props to render your playlist and pass in whatever initial playlist you'd like. ( I personally prefer this method )

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I am working on refactoring this component now.